# Trying to install SQLExpress tools goes nuts, attempts to install Ati Radeon driver

Tags: installation, sql-server

This applies to all of the downloads with tools, the database itself isn't the problem.

Attempting to follow what's going on I find it unpacking itself into a directory on the drive with the most space (never mind it picked the slowest drive!) and then it runs the installer for my video card--the file already exists on my system, it wasn't in the package.  At this point the entire directory structure it created has been killed, all that's left is the running ATI installer.

(And to add insult to injury, the installer gets stuck trying to figure out what it's supposed to do and has to be killed with the task manager.)

All I can figure is that there was a GUID collision or something.  It's certainly up there with the weirdest errors I have ever seen.

Win 7/64.

Edit:  Microsoft just put up a new file, it behaves properly.  Obviously their bug.

Comment: OK, so what's your question exactly? :)  What have you done in attempts to get it to install properly?  Which OS?

Comment: @techie007 Obviously I'm trying to get it to install.  I'm at a loss as to what to try, this error is so strange and Google is coming up blank on it.

Comment: You'll have to forgive me, but my crystal ball is in the shop.  :)What errors are you speaking of?  Can you provide screenshots or text of said errors?

Comment: @techie007 Running the Radeon installer rather than the installer it should be running.  There's no error message, just the wrong program.